# Find the number whose digits have the highest sum in a given range

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

For a given input `n`, the task is to find the `largest integer that is <= n and has the highest digit sum`.

For example:

```
solve(100) = 99. Digit Sum for 99 = 9 + 9 = 18. No other number <= 100 has a higher digit sum.
solve(10) = 9
solve(48) = 48. Note that 39 is also an option, but 48 is larger.

Input range is 0 < n < 1e11
```

What have I tried?

I tried 2 methods. Firstly, I tried getting each digit with Math operations like this:

```
public static long solve(long n)
{
    var answer = 0;
    var highestSum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        var temp = i;
        var sum = 0;
        while (temp > 0)
        {
            sum += temp % 10;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        if (sum >= highestSum)
        {
            highestSum = sum;
            answer = i;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

My second try, I tried using Linq extensions, like this:

```
public static long solve(long n)
{
    var answer = 0;
    var highestSum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        var sum = i.ToString().Sum(x => x - '0');
        if (sum >= highestSum)
        {
            highestSum = sum;
            answer = i;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Both of my solutions seem to return the correct value and work for smaller values, but for larger input, they seem to take a very long time to execute. How to make it run through numbers faster? Is there a specific algorithm for this task, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: seems a good  fit for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I agree, but unfortunately some one will answer, at least, this is the general consensus I see.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ well, it´s not neccessarily bad to answer, as it may be migrated anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere no, it's not bad to answer at all. I am just saying, there's another site for questions like this, since according to the OP it works, but is looking for alternatives which would lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: Your mistake is that you are relying on brute force, instead of *thinking about the problem* and seeing a shortcut.

Comment: @Beta I have considered starting from the last number and going back, but I wasn't sure if that would actually help. I am most definitely missing a certain pattern here. Any hints?

Comment: Imagine you have a large n, thirty digits long, and you delegate this task to two servants. They come back to you with two different solutions; each is a large number less than n, and they are the same except that somewhere in the middle, the first number has a '4' and the second number has a '3'. What occurs to you? (Now stop asking for help with a question from a competitive coding site.)

Comment: @Beta _Now stop asking for help with a question from a competitive coding site_ I disagree. Devs can ask for help.

Comment: @vivek_23: "Devs"? A dev must learn to think about such problems; the OP will learn nothing from being handed the answer.

Comment: @Beta OP has tried 2 methods and is unable to come up with an optimized one. So it's perfectly valid to ask for help. Not all people implicitly think on the right path. Some need help and it's fine. Obviously all questions on SO are asked because they needed help. If people tried and got success all the time, this site wouldn't have existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can achieve this O(number of digits in n)

We can achieve this if we iteratively reduce a digit and change all other digits on its right to 9.

Let `n` be our current number.

We can find next number using the below :

`b` is a power of 10 to represent position of current digit. After every iteration we reduce `n` to `n/10` and change `b` to `b*10`.

We use `(n – 1) * b + (b – 1);`

For eg, if the number is `n = 521` and `b = 1`, then

`(521 – 1) * 1 + (1-1)` which gives you `520`, which is the thing we need to do, reduce the position number by `1` and replace all other numbers to the right by `9`.

After `n /= 10` gives you `n` as `52` and `b*=10` gives you `b` as `10`, which is again executed as `(52-1)*(10) + 9` which gives you `519`, which is what we have to do, reduce the current index by `1` and increase all other rights by `9`.

```
static int findMax(int x) 
{ 
   int b = 1, ans = x; 
   while (x!=0)  
   { 
      int cur = (x - 1) * b + (b - 1); 
      if (sumOfDigits(cur) >= sumOfDigits(ans) && cur > ans)) 
         ans = cur; 
   
       x /= 10; 
       b *= 10; 
    } 
       
    return ans; 
 }

int sumOfDigits(int a) 
{ 
    int sum = 0; 
    while (a) 
    { 
        sum += a % 10; 
        a /= 10; 
    } 
    return sum; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is brilliant, but I was dead-set on figuring out a way to determine the correct answer without actually summing the digits and comparing the sums to each other.

I tried a few things (as you can see if you look at the edit history), but I couldn't find the formula. In desperation, I wrote a utility to show me all the numbers from `1` to `9999999` that did not have a smaller number with a larger sum to see what pattern I was missing by not looking on a large enough scale.

I was somewhat surprised that only `253` numbers out of the first `10` million have the largest sum compared to their lessers! Somehow I thought that number would be bigger.

Also, it turns out that there is an obvious pattern that appears fairly quickly, and it remained constant for 10 million iterations, so I think it's a good one.

Here's a small sample of some blocks of consecutive output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
18,19,28,29,38,39,48,49,
58,59,68,69,78,79,88,89,98,99,189,198

8899,8989,8998,8999,
9899,9989,9998,9999,
18999,19899,19989,19998,19999

98999,99899,99989,99998,99999,
189999,198999,199899,199989,199998,199999

7899999,7989999,7998999,7999899,7999989,7999998,7999999,
8899999,8989999,8998999,8999899,8999989,8999998,8999999,
9899999,9989999,9998999,9999899,9999989,9999998,9999999
```

It's so obviously clear!

- If the number is one digit, then it's the highest.
- If all but the first digit are either all `9`'s or all `9`'s with a single `8`, then it's sum is the highest.
- Otherwise the highest number is the one whose first digit is one less than the original, followed by all `9`'s.

Here's a code implementation:

```
public static long Solve(long n)
{
    if (HasValidSuffix(n)) return n;

    long firstDigit;
    int numDigits;

    // Loop to determine the first digit and number of digits in the input
    for (firstDigit = n, numDigits = 1; firstDigit > 9; firstDigit /= 10, numDigits++) ;

    return Enumerable.Range(0, numDigits - 1)
        .Aggregate(firstDigit - 1, (accumulator, next) => accumulator * 10 + 9);
}

// Returns true for positive numbers less than 10 or 
// numbers that end in either all 9's or all 9's and one 8
public static bool HasValidSuffix(long input)
{
    var foundAnEight = false;

    for (var n = input; n > 9; n /= 10)
    {
        var lastDigit = n % 10;
        if (lastDigit < 8) return false;
        if (lastDigit == 9) continue;
        if (foundAnEight) return false;
        foundAnEight = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not handle digits > 2, whereas jasmeet's answer is general and handles all digit cases.  The premise of the answers is identical.

Comment: 37650, the answer should be 29999, and NOT 37649.  29999 = 38.  37649 = 29.  38 > 29.  As mentioned, this answer does not handle digits > 2.

Comment: 37690 the answer should be 29999 = 38.  You will get: 37689 = 33, as you break early due to the last digit of 8 being encountered during iteration 2 (8 > 7).  Not comparing the sum is trivial difference.  The main difference and technique are the same, but jasmeet does not short cut out.

Comment: @John Thanks for all your feedback. Forced me to look for a better pattern and I finally found it. I *think* the new code solves for all cases.